# Perl - how to create dynamic multi level hash using array of elements as keys

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, hash, complex-data-types

I like to create a multi level hash by using an array that stores the elements to form the multi level keys. Example:

`@elements = ('level1','level2','level3');`

And want something like this:

`$hashdata{level1}{level2}{level3} = 'store anything i want';`

is there something that can easily do this? package?

thanks

Comment: See [Data::Diver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver)

Comment: Another  related tool [Deep::Hash::Utils](https://metacpan.org/pod/Deep::Hash::Utils).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A most well-known tool is probably [Data::Diver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver)

```
use warnings;
use strict;    
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

use Data::Diver qw(DiveVal);

my @elems = qw(lev1 lev2 lev3);

my %hash;

DiveVal(\%hash, @elems) = "value";

dd \%hash;
```

The `DiveVal` is an [lvalue subroutine](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Lvalue-subroutines) (can be assigned to), and which autovivifies when it can.